# grffile package not working with includepdf when the command is in a "newcommand"

Tags: external-files, pdfpages

I'm able to include file names with spaces when I use the includepdf alone but when it's included into a newcommand , I cant seem to make it work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*\ifpdfexists[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1.pdf}{\includepdf[pages={-,{}},fitpaper=true]{#1}\cleardoublepage}{\relax}}

\begin{document}

\ifpdfexists{File Name}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I was told to use this package for file names with spaces. It worked fine until I tried my `\newcommand`.

Comment: nothing to do with `\newcommand` You need `\IfFileExists{"#1.pdf"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works fine for me if I add quotes in the first argument of `\IfFileExists`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*\ifpdfexists[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{"#1.pdf"}{\includepdf[pages={-,{}},fitpaper=true]{#1}\cleardoublepage}{\relax}}

\begin{document}

\ifpdfexists{File Name}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh my god!That was it? You just saved my life!Ok maybe not that much, but the solution was so simple! Thanks!!

Comment: @Pedneault75 You're welcome.